# Nagios: check_nt and USEDDISKSPACE

Tags: nagios

I can manually run check_nt with USEDDISKSPACE, but I get **check_nt: could not parse arguments** when called from the configs. The other one that isn't working is SERVICESTATE. MEMUSE, CPULOAD and UPTIME are working fine. Anybody have any ideas? I've tried hard coding all the arguments in the commands.cfg but to no avail.

**commands.cfg**

```
define command {
command_name check_nt_DISK_C
command_line $USER1$/check_nt -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 12489 -l C -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -v USEDDISKSPACE
}
```

**services.cfg**

```
define service {
use generic-service
host_name <server>
service_description USED DISK SPACE
check_command check_nt!DISK_C!-w 80 -c 90
check_interval 1
retry_interval 1
max_check_attempts 3
notification_options w,u,c,r
contact_groups toneman
notification_interval 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following commands.cfg this should be something like:

```
check_command check_nt_DISK_C!80 90
```

Comment: I can run the command like this without issue.  Thanks, but your suggestion hasn't changed my result.
 ./check_nt -H <IPAddy> -p 12489 -l C -w 80 -c 90 -v USEDDISKSPACE

Comment: Actually, it should be `check_command check_nt_DISK_C!80!90`. You need a `!` for each argument.

Answer (score 0):

I hardcoded the arguments and just created new command definitions for each of the drives.  A little extra code, but at least it works.

command_line $USER1$/check_nt -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 12489 -w 80 -c 90 -l F -v USEDDISKSPACE